# How to calculate power from this diagram?

Tags: power

I need to calculate the apparent power, active power and reactive power and I only got this diagram ( in german ):

[image]

So the equation for active power is $$P = \int_0^T u(t)i(t) \, \mathrm{d} x$$

Edit: Adjusted my solution to the answers:

$$ i(t) = kx+d = -{2t \over T} +1$$ 
$$ u(t) = 0.5 \rightarrow t=[0,T/2] $$
$$ u(t) = -0.5 \rightarrow t=[T/2,T] $$

$$P = {\int_0^{T/2}( {-t \over T}  +0.5 \,) \mathrm{d} t + \int_{T/2}^T ({t \over T} -0.5) \, \mathrm{d} t \over T} = \frac{1}{4}W$$

Complex power: $$S = RMS(i(t)) * RMS (u(t))$$
$$RMS(i(t)) = \frac{peak}{\sqrt{3}} = 0,577$$
$$S= 0,289$$
$$Q = \sqrt{S^2-P^2}= 0,144$$
$$cos(\alpha) = \frac{P}{S}= 0,866$$

Comment: Shouldn't P be 0.5 W? Because 0.25W is only for one half.

Comment: No.  You are confusing energy and power.  Power is energy per time.  The total energy delivered to the load grows constantly, but the power averages the same over any whole number of half cycles.  That is because the time increases along with the total energy.  For example, a 60 W light bulb is still 60 W whether you run it for 1 minute or 2 minutes.

Comment: Seems plausible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are making this way too complicated.

From inspection you can see that during the first half of the period shown, you have a steady voltage of 500 mV.  The power is then just the average of the current times this voltage, which is 250 mW.  From inspection again you can see that the second half of the period is the same as the first half with the signs of the voltage and current flipped.  This obviously yields the same power again, 250 mW.

The instantaneous power is a triangle wave with peaks at 0 and 500 mW, and average of 250 mW (unless I'm misunderstanding what that diagram is showing).

### Added:

I forgot to mention about calculating reative power.

One way to get that is to derive the power factor.  The power factor is usually described as the cosine of the phase angle between the current and voltage assuming both are sines.  However, it also has a more general definition that is more appropriate in this case.  You can think of the power factor as the ratio of true power to the product of RMS current and voltage.

In this case, the RMS voltage is obvious, which is 500 mV.  From inspection you can see that the current is symmetric and repeating, so you only have to solve for the RMS current of a ramp from 1 to 0.  From symmetry we can see that this must be the same as a ramp from 0 to 1, which will make the equation a little easier.

In other words, find the RMS current of I(t) = t from 0 to 1.  To do that, first square the function, which is then t^2.  The average of that from 0 to 1 is 1/3, and then the square root of that is 0.577.  So the RMS voltage is 500 mV, the RMS current is 577 mA, and the product of the two is 289 mW.  From above the real power is only 250 mW, so the power factor is 250mW/289mW = 0.866.  The reactive power is

sqrt(289mW^2 - 250mW^2) = 144 mW

Again, there is no need to make this complicated.

Comment: I like more the explanation with apparent power than the one with power factor.

Answer (score 2):

First: I would represent I as function of t instead of x:

$$ i (t) = -{2t \over T} +1 $$

and

$$ u(t) = 0.5 \rightarrow t=[0,T/2] $$
$$ u(t) = -0.5 \rightarrow t=[T/2,T] $$

Than you can assume that their (base) frequency is equal, because they have the same period T. They appear to have also the same phase, because are both positive in the first semi-period and negative in the second.

So the power will be:

$$ p(t) = 0.5* \left( \frac{-2t}{T} \right) +0.5 = \left( \frac{-t}{T} \right)  +0.5 \rightarrow t=[0,T/2] $$
$$ p(t) = -0.5* \left( \frac{-2t}{T} \right) +0.5 = \left( \frac{t}{T} \right)  -0.5 \rightarrow t=[T/2,T] $$

Now you apply the integral you showed to calculate the average:

$$ P = {\int_0^{T/2} \left( {-t \over T}  +0.5 \, \right) \mathrm{d} t + \int_{T/2}^T \left( {t \over T} -0.5 \right) \, \mathrm{d} t \over T} = \frac{1}{4}W $$

(I may be wrong but if you do it graphically you should obtain this)

For the reactive power see Olin's answer :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my solution would be 0. That cant be. Also I dont know how you got -2/T. -2 is the pitch but why 1/T?

Comment: -2/T because i(t) drops of 2 (A?) in the time T; try to substitute the values and you should get it right; then, cannot be 0 because the signals are both positive or negative at the same time

Comment: Ok thanks. But I have to correct you. The reactive power is not zero. I met with my professor today and he told me that you cant decide if the signals are in phase or not in this case. He also said that the reactive power is not zero but he wasn't in the mood to explain it to me ...

Comment: No, I didn't want to say that they have no phase. It's just that the current is not the same type of signal as the voltage. (square wave) And that was my professor's argument to say that I can't decide that it is in phase although it seems as it is.

Comment: @clabacchio: No, reactive power is not zero. Having the signs always match doesn't guarantee a power factor of 1, which is what is necessary for reactive power to be 0. You can't really talk about phase here since the signals are not sinusoids, but that doesn't mean there can't be reactive power. It should be obvious from inspection that there is reactive power since the voltage and current aren't proportional to each other. Remember that power factor of 1, reactive power of 0, and load being purely resistive all say the same thing.  Clearly the load is not resistive.

Comment: @OlinLathrop you're right, but the only definition of reactive power that I've found uses sin(phi), and your power factor explanation, although completely correct (I've upvoted it) sounds strange because I consider power factor as active power over apparent power, and this is sort of reverting the concept.

Comment: @clabacchio: I removed my downvote since you fixed the answer.  As you say (I think), power factor is real power over the power magnitude.  That's why it is the cosine of the phase angle when a phase angle makes sense to talk about.  Think of the former as the real definition, with the second being only a convenience when both voltage and current are sinusoids.  In this case you could work backwards from the power factor of .866 and declare the phase angle to be 30 deg, but that's not very meaningful since neither voltage or current is very sinusoidal.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I don't completely agree and I'll try to demonstrate it :) But what I think is that the phase (which you say should be 30°) can be obtained from the harmonic components of the Fourier approximation of the signal. And that it should be possible (I'll work on this too) to obtain the reactive power from the signals functions, without using the power factor...stay tuned :)

Answer (score 2):

$$S^2=P^2+Q^2$$

- complex power \$S=V\cdot I\$
- apparent power \$|S|=|V\cdot I|=V_\text{RMS}\cdot I_\text{RMS}\$
- real power \$P=\mathbb{R}\{S\}\$
- reactive power \$Q=\mathbb{I}\{S\}\$

The current-voltage product is positive for the entire period, so power flows towards the load at all times; reactive power is zero.

Don't try to define the voltage function U(t) over the entire period. Instead break up the integral into two parts: \$\int_0^{T/2}U_1(t)I(t)dt+\int_{T/2}^TU_2(t)I(t)dt\$, where *U<sub>1</sub>=0.5V* and *U<sub>2</sub>=-0.5V*.

Comment: Well I also told my professor that the reactive power is zero. But he told me that it is wrong and that I can't say that the two signals are in phase because it is only possible with sinus signals. I am a bit confused now ...

Comment: Just a tip: usually time-dependent variables are represented with lowercase, to distinguish them from rms and-or average...

Comment: At least what you said was correct as far as it went, but how about actually answering the question of what the real and reactive powers are?

Comment: Olin has demonstrated that reactive power is different than 0, I would suggest to remove that statement :)

Comment: @clabacchio, I hadn't heard of his definition of reactive power. Feel free to vote mine down.

Comment: @tyblu I'm not going to downvote, but actually you can agree it's not zero: it is only when the two signals are perfectly superimposable, and this is not the case; I think it can be proven by an harmonic analysis, but calculating apparent and active power is another (valid) way. I would exclude the power factor because it's an indirect "quality" indicator but, well, it works.