# How to calculate power from this diagram? (Another one)

Tags: power

I asked [a similar question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/26990/how-to-calculate-power-from-this-diagram) before, but now with another diagram.
I have a solution but I am not sure if it is right.

[image]

First half:
$$i_1(t)=\frac{t}{T}A$$
$$u_1(t)=1V$$

Second half:
$$i_2(t)=\frac{t}{T}A$$
$$u_2(t)=-1V$$

Power:
$$P =
{\int_0^{T/2}( {t \over T}   \,) \mathrm{d} t + \int_{T/2}^T ({-t \over T} ) \, \mathrm{d} t \over T} =
- \frac{1}{4}W$$

Comment: You definitely should learn to write your units in your equations. They're the first indication that what you're doing makes sense.

Comment: -1/4 (what?) = 1/4 (what?) ????

Comment: Your current should be defined as \$i(t)=\frac{t}{T} [A]\$. At the end of a period it reaches `1 A` not `2 A`.

Comment: Well, I wrote it for the first and second half of the period.  So its t in the time of T/2 and that is 2t/T. When I use it like that i get the correct value. When I use it like you say, I get -1/4.

Comment: Of course not! The function isn't defined by the domain, and it's the same as before.

Comment: Whats correct now? Olin said it has to be 0,5 W. But when I use t/T the integral returns -1/4 and not -1/2. I am completely confused now, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easiest done in two parts, for the first and second halves of the repeating waveform.  This time the average power will obviously be negative since the power magnitude in the second half clearly is larger than in the first half, and the first half is obviously positive and the second negative.  This means the load is supplying net power.

The total power magnitude is the RMS voltage times the RMS current.  The RMS voltage is obviously 1 V.  The current is a ramp from 0 to 1, or I(t) = t.  That squared is t^2, the average of that is 1/3, and the square root of that is 0.577.  The power magnitude is therefore 1 V * 577 mA = 577 mW.

The real power is the integral of the instantaneous voltage and current over one repeating cycle.  From inspection, this is 250 mW in the first half and -750 mW in the second half, for a total of -500 mW.

The power factor is -500 mW / 577 mW = -0.866.  Often the absolute value of the power factor is quoted with a statement as to whether the reactive load is inductive or capacitive.  You can take the arc cosine of the power factor to get the phase angle of -30 deg in this case, but that has little meaning when the voltage and current are so non-sinusoidal.

The total complex power is the vector sum of the real and reactive power.  Since we know the real power and the power magnitude, we can calculate the reactive power, which is -289 mW.  The sign only indicates whether it is capacitive or inductive (whether it is a +90 deg or -90 deg).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It would be a bit easier to understand if you would use some formular coding and not just text.

Comment: Can u tell me whats wrong with my integral? I get -0.75W for the real power.

Comment: @madmax it's true, but this time you should be able to solve the exercise with the former question, so please take the answer as is and try to do some work :) And your integral is wrong because you've taken it from the other question, and now i(t) is different

Comment: Here it looks logic that you add up the two halves for the real power. But why don't you add it up at my other question? I don't get that.

Comment: @madmax: I don't remember the details of your other question, but I sortof remember that it was easier to solve by inspection.  Here the sign of the power changes, whereas in your other question it was always positive.

Comment: There is a link in the first sentence of my question. I am confused because you wrote that for the first half its 250 mW  and for the 2nd also, so for the whole period it should be 500mW?

Comment: I am sorry but I think the -500 mW for the real power are wrong. Because as we know by now my integral in the question is correct and it ouputs -250 mW.

Comment: @madmax: I'm not going to dig thru your equations to see what you did wrong, but both clabacchio and I get -500 mW. See his answer for the detailed equations. My logic is a lot simpler. During the first half you have power changing linearly from 0 to 500 mW, for 250 mW average. During the second half it goes linearly from -500 mW to -1 W, for a average of -750 mW. Averaging these total powers over a cycle yields -500 mW since the two halves for which power was computed above are equal.

Comment: Ok, I didn't see his edited answer but it is also wrong. 0.125+0.125-0.5 = -.025 ! and not - 0.5.

Answer (score 3):

Olin has already answered, but I would point to some corrections for your formulas:

You wrote:

> first half:
>   $$i_1(t)=\frac{2t}{T}$$
>   $$u_1(t)=1$$
>   second half:
>   $$i_2(t)=\frac{2t}{T}+0.5$$
>   $$u_2(t)=-1$$

But $$i(t) = \frac{t}{T}$$  in the whole period, so you get the wrong power.

And the power becomes (normalizing T to 1):
$$P = {\int_0^{T/2} \left( {t \over T}   \, \right) \, dt + \int_{T/2}^T \left({-t \over T} \right) \, \,dt \over T} =
{ \left[ \frac{t^2}{2} \right] _0^\frac{1}{2}}-{ \left[ \frac{t^2}{2} \right] _\frac{1}{2}^1}=
\frac{1}{8}-0-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{8}=
- \frac{1}{4}W$$

Comment: Corrected that.

Comment: I am sorry, it's wrong: 0.125+0.125-0.5 = -.025 ! and not - 0.5

Comment: @madmax you're right, it's 0.25. But now don't ask about power anymore ;)

Comment: I am sorry, 6 days till exam, but I don't feel very confident. ;)